# Cors error caused by calling an external API from ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know CORS is a very common problem but I cannot find a temporary solution for my application.
This is the API I am trying to call in my app: https://github.com/nickypangers/passport-visa-api

Here's my code for calling it:

```
  const getVisaReq = async (userPassport: string, dest: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const res: any = await fetch(`https://rough-sun-2523.fly.dev/api/${userPassport}/${dest}`, {
        // FIXME: cors error
        headers: new Headers({
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "Get,POST,PATCH,OPTIONS",
        }),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  console.log(getVisaReq("HK", "US"));
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://rough-sun-2523.fly.dev/api/HK/US' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have searched for a lot of solutions, like setting mode to no-cors, installing plugins, etc. But none of them works or creates other errors. What is the proper way to deal with this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually mean CORS?  If your calls are getting rejected you need to modify the backend server to give the headers matching the domain you are calling from.  If you do not control the API you must have whoever owns it change it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API is not controlled by you, and you can not change its headers, you can create a proxy server for it.

Spin up an express server that call the API for you and returns the results back to the client.